# Ignore kwargs in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a function that should call an other function with the correct parameters:

```
def my_function(json=None):
    url = f"some url..."
    if json is not None:
        requests.post(url, json=json)
    else:
        requests.post(url)
```

is this equivalent to:

```
def my_function(json=None):
    url = f"some url..."
    requests.post(url, json=json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes in this case it is equivalent, as the [signature for post](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/api.py#L105) is

```
def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
```

Note that in general passing `None` through is not necessarily equivalent if the default argument were something else such as

```
def post(url, json={})
```

in that case `{}` is not the same as `None` and could have the potential to follow a different code path.